# How to calculate time duration in sql server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

[image: This is my result I want to calculate time duration between checkin and checkout like for example]

> This is My First Condition. suppose CheckIn Time is Greater Than Check Out Time so How Can I calculate Time Duration

```
StaffName | attendDate| staffid| firmId| Shiftname | AttendId| CheckIn| CheckOut | Total Duration
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Kiran A Veri  |   2017-03-28   |5146  |1  | Night  | 34584   |18:00:00| 03:00:00  | 09:00:00
```

> This is my second condition. If check in time is less than checkout time so how to manage both condition in this Query?

```
 StaffName | attendDate| staffid| firmId| Shiftname | AttendId| CheckIn| CheckOut | Total Duration
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Ritesh B Patel  |   2017-03-28   |5146  |1  | General | 34584   |10:06:06| 19:35:46  | 09:29:00
```

Comment: What is the type of the `CheckIn` and `CheckOut` columns?

Comment: Check in and check out is a time

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen CheckIn is Time and checkOut also Time Please Send me Query How to calculate Total Duration

Comment: Which sql-server version?

Comment: @McNets Sql Server 2014

Comment: @sqlZim Can you help me in this scinario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part:

Use a CASE WHEN CheckIn > CheckOut in conjunction with DATEDIFF.

For the second part:

Build a datetime or time field and [convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187928.aspx) it using Style=108 (hh.mm.ss)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE TEST(ID int, CheckIn time, CheckOut time);
> INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(1, '03:00:00', '10:00:00'),(2, '10:26:13', '03:12:15'),(3, '18:00:00', '03:00:00');
>
> -- Below SQL-Server 2012
> SELECT CASE WHEN CheckIn > CheckOut
>             THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), 86400 - DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, CheckOut, CheckIn), '00:00:00'), 108)
>             ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, CheckIn, CheckOut), '00:00:00'), 108)
>             END Elapsed_Time
> FROM   TEST
>
> -- SQL-Server 2012 or above
> SELECT CASE WHEN CheckIn > CheckOut
>             THEN FORMAT(86400 - DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, CheckOut, CheckIn), '00:00:00'), 'hh\:mm\:ss')
>             ELSE FORMAT(DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, CheckIn, CheckOut), '00:00:00'), 'hh\:mm\:ss')
>             END Elapsed_Time
> FROM   TEST
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | Elapsed_Time |
> | :----------- |
> | 07:00:00     |
> | 16:46:02     |
> | 09:00:00     |
>
> | Elapsed_Time |
> | :----------- |
> | 07:00:00     |
> | 04:46:02     |
> | 09:00:00     |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=05de7eb3ebc028680396687b14ab2a6e)*

Comment: See suppose My CheckIn time is 18:00:00 and CheckOut Time is  03:00:00 so my total duration is 09:00:00 But its Showing 15:00:00

Comment: edited, check it now